# Причина ошибки, допущенной в стандартном бланке "Сбербанка"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

В отделениях "Сбербанка" предлагаются для заполнения бланки с текстом: "Положить во вклад". С чем связана эта грамматическая ошибка? Чем она вызвана?

Comment: Возможно и ошибка, но если Вы уверены, то где доказательства? И как правильно: на вклад?

Comment: Конечно, правильно: "положить на вклад". Действительно, в словарях данное выражение не приводится, не комментируется. Доказательство - только традиционная практика словоупотребления.  В ряде случаев (например в периоды, когда словарей еще не существовало) практика образцового словоупотребления служила единственным критерием нормы. П

Answer (score 3):

В банковской сфере есть формальное выражение "**разместить средства во вклад**" (не в ячейку или ещё как-то, а положить деньги в банк *в форме вклада*) и производное от него "**делать взносы во вклад**" (который уже имеется) - вот юридически значимые документы Сбербанка, где это встречается:

https://www.sberbank.ru/common/img/uploaded/engage/vklad_doc/udbo/Pravila_razmeshcheniya_vkladov.pdf
http://www.sberbank.ru/common/img/uploaded/vklad/Usloviya_po_razmeshcheniu_denezhnykh_sredstv_vo_vklad.pdf

Аналогичная фразеология от других банков:

http://www.soyuzny.ru/person/vklady/vklad_victory.pdf
http://www.fbbank.ru/corporate-clients/raise-funds/
https://otc.ru/tenders/region/g-moskva/10417601/31704763209-razmeshhenie-denezhny%60x-sredstv-vo-vklad-depozit-v-bank-vtb-pao
http://www.ncubank.ru/index.php/depozity

Ну а от "**разместить в**" недалеко и до "**положить в**". В этом выражении есть своя логика: не всегда можно выразиться безупречно "**положить на счёт вклада**" - только если вклад уже имеется (то же в случае упрощения "положить на вклад"). В быту этих выражений почти не употребляют, говорят просто "**положить в банк**", поэтому формальные банковские выражения непривычны и могут восприниматься как ошибки. Любопытно, что отзвуки упрощения "положить на вклад" можно встретить в документах - в форме "перечислить **со** вклада" (с предлогом, обратным "на"); видимо, "со счёта вклада" слишком громоздко.

Резюме: можно отнестись к этому как к банковской профессиональной фразеологии.

Answer (score 1):

Вклад - денежная сумма, внесённая в банк на хранение. На мой взгляд, вклад можно внести, пополнить, но *в него* ничего нельзя положить, а положить *на него* можно только в сленговом значении выражения "положить на".