# "Деньги во вкладе" или "деньги на вкладе"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: *деньги во вкладе* или *деньги на вкладе*?

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта неверны. Вклад - денежная сумма, внесённая в банк на хранение. Правильно: деньги в банке, на банковском счете. Подробнее [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435284/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Вот [ответ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=251866) Грамоты:

> Вопрос № 251866

Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: а) разместить средства на вкладе б) разместить средства во вкладе в) какой-то другой вариант? Заранее благодарна.

> Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Можно сказать: разместить средства на счете, на депозите.